# Android print view

Tags: android, printing, android-print-framework

My target is to print certain View to pdf, without using screenshot. Does that possible? I have already tried next code with no success. This code properly creates pdf document, but my target is to inflate View and just print it. Any ideas?

```
public class PrintClass extends PrintDocumentAdapter {

    private int pageHeight;
    private int pageWidth;
    public PdfDocument myPdfDocument;
    public int totalpages = 1;
    Context context;
    public PrintClass(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayout(PrintAttributes oldAttributes, PrintAttributes newAttributes, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback callback, Bundle extras) {
        myPdfDocument = new PrintedPdfDocument(context, newAttributes);
        pageHeight = newAttributes.getMediaSize().getHeightMils()/1000 * 72;
        pageWidth = newAttributes.getMediaSize().getWidthMils()/1000 * 72;
        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled() ) {
            callback.onLayoutCancelled();
            return;
        }
        if (totalpages > 0) {
            PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder = new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("print_output.pdf").setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT).setPageCount(totalpages);
            PrintDocumentInfo info = builder.build();
            callback.onLayoutFinished(info, true);
        } else {
            callback.onLayoutFailed("Page count is zero.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onWrite(PageRange[] pageRanges, ParcelFileDescriptor destination, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback callback) {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalpages; i++) {
            if (pageInRange(pageRanges, i)) {
                PdfDocument.PageInfo newPage = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, i).create();
                PdfDocument.Page page = myPdfDocument.startPage(newPage);
                if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
                    callback.onWriteCancelled();
                    myPdfDocument.close();
                    myPdfDocument = null;
                    return;
                }
                drawPage(page, i);
                myPdfDocument.finishPage(page);
            }
        }
        try {
            myPdfDocument.writeTo(new FileOutputStream(destination.getFileDescriptor()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            callback.onWriteFailed(e.toString());
            return;
        } finally {
            myPdfDocument.close();
            myPdfDocument = null;
        }
        callback.onWriteFinished(pageRanges);
    }

    private boolean pageInRange(PageRange[] pageRanges, int page) {
        for (int i = 0; i<pageRanges.length; i++) {
            if ((page >= pageRanges[i].getStart()) &&
                    (page <= pageRanges[i].getEnd()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void drawPage(PdfDocument.Page page, int pagenumber) {
        Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
        pagenumber++; // Make sure page numbers start at 1
        int titleBaseLine = 72;
        int leftMargin = 54;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setTextSize(40);
        canvas.drawText("Test Print Document Page " + pagenumber, leftMargin, titleBaseLine, paint);
        paint.setTextSize(14);
        canvas.drawText("This is some test content to verify that custom document printing works", leftMargin, titleBaseLine + 35, paint);
        if (pagenumber % 2 == 0)
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        else
            paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = page.getInfo();
        canvas.drawCircle(pageInfo.getPageWidth()/2, pageInfo.getPageHeight()/2, 150, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?